# mysql connection from a different domain

Tags: php, mysql, cross-domain

I have website `example.com`, it contains a MySQL server. I have another `example.org`, both are different domains. I want to access the MySQL server on `example.com` from `example.org`. How would it be possible?

Comment: jus t a workaround , try calling a page on domain a from domain b , and do all the processing of mysql in domain a on that page

Comment: Different domains are not necessarily on separate servers, if they are both on the same server (with the mysql), you don't need to do anything at all -- in scripts from either domain you use `localhost`.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set the remote `example.com` when you call the database connection initialization function. For example:

```
mysqli_connect("example.com", 'username', 'password', 'database name');
```

But you will need to check whether `example.com`'s MySQL server is set to accept connections from other hosts (see the `bind-address` directive in your `my.cnf` or `my.ini`), and that the `username` you connect with is set to be able to connect from external domains.

Consider the following *Users* page of phpMyAdmin: [image: Example user privilege list]

It is clear that only user `test` has access from outside domains (`%` in the *Host* field). Not shown on the image, but user `test` has full privilege on the database called `test`. The other users are bound to the local domain, even though the server is set to accept connections from the outside, when authenticating, users are thrown a denial.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to remote MySQL server. Just have to make sure that the remote server is binding to public address.

Here's how: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/mysql/switch-mysql-to-listen-on-tcp/

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to any MySQL server wherever it is, as long as it's setup for remote connection.

Depending on your operating system and webserver of choice, the settings will be different, but a good place to start is by (if using linux) looking here:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

In this file you will find:

```
bind-address: 127.0.0.1
```

You will change this to the IP address of the server and then restart the mysql daemon.

..and now you can connect remotely ;)